# Actualizar tabla desde un select añadiendo la fecha en que se ejecuto la consulta

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta select que me inserta los resultados en otra tabla necesito poder realizar la misma consulta periódicamente pero que me agregue un campo fecha con la fecha de ejecución de la consulta en cada registro para poder saber cuales son los registros más viejos y cuales más nuevos, poderlos organizar por fecha.

Esta es la consulta

```
INSERT INTO Resultadotb

SELECT     gen_unidadcontable.nombre AS 'Unidad Contable', inv_categoria.nombre AS Categoría, gen_producto.codigo, gen_producto.descripcion, SUM(inv_existencia.cantidad) AS Cantidad, 
                      gen_medida.descripcion AS UM, ROUND(AVG(inv_existencia.preciomn), 2) AS PrecioCostoMN, SUM(inv_existencia.importemn) AS ImporteMN, ROUND(AVG(inv_existencia.preciomlc), 2) 
                      AS PrecioCostoCUC, SUM(inv_existencia.importemlc) AS ImporteCUC, con_cuenta.clave AS Cuenta, con_cuentanat.descripcion AS Descrip_Cuenta

FROM         inv_existencia INNER JOIN
                      gen_producto ON inv_existencia.idproducto = gen_producto.idproducto INNER JOIN
                      inv_categoria ON inv_existencia.idcategoria = inv_categoria.idcategoria INNER JOIN
                      inv_existenciaalm ON inv_existencia.idexistencia = inv_existenciaalm.idexistencia INNER JOIN
                      gen_almacen ON inv_existenciaalm.idalmacen = gen_almacen.idalmacen INNER JOIN
                      gen_unidadcontable ON gen_almacen.idunidad = gen_unidadcontable.idunidad INNER JOIN
                      gen_medida ON gen_producto.idmedida = gen_medida.idmedida INNER JOIN
                      con_cuenta ON inv_existencia.idcuentamn = con_cuenta.idcuenta INNER JOIN
                      con_cuentanat ON con_cuenta.idcuenta = con_cuentanat.idcuenta

WHERE     (inv_existencia.cantidad > 0) AND (inv_categoria.nombre != 'Insumo' )

GROUP BY gen_unidadcontable.nombre, inv_categoria.nombre, gen_producto.codigo, gen_producto.descripcion, gen_medida.descripcion, con_cuenta.clave, con_cuentanat.descripcion

ORDER BY inv_categoria.nombre, con_cuenta.clave
```

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En cuanto a tu pregunta, es necesario que agregues código de lo que realizas, además deberías subir el esquema de tu tabla o el DDL. Tu pregunta tiene fallas de formato, y eso hace que sea difícil o imposible responder. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seria bueno saber las estructuras de las tablas pero bueno,

inserto into tabla2(
select * , getdate()
from tabla1

)